# Issue to order products by price in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I want to order products by price with one link for low to high and the other high to low,
But after I click "low to high" or "high to low" the order is not changing, it stays on the same page but the url is changing.

this is the function in the controller:

```
public function products(Request $request, $category_url, $sort= 'ASC')
{
    Product::getProducts($category_url, self:: $data);

    if ( $category1 = Categorie::where('url', '=', $category_url)->first() ) {

        $products = Product::where('categorie_id', $category1->getAttribute('id'))->orderBy('price', $sort)->get();

        return view('content.products', self::$data , compact('products', 'sort')); 
    }
}
```

this is the route:

```
  Route::get('shop/{category_url}/sorting-{sort?}', 'ShopController@products');
```

those are the link from the view, the view is content.products

```html
  <a href="  {{ url('shop/'.$category['url'].'/sorting-asc')}}" style="color:black"> High to low</a> |
  <a href="  {{ url('shop/'.$category['url'].'/sorting-desc')}}" style="color:black">Low to high</a>
```

the model:

```
class Product extends Model {


static public function getProducts($category_url, &$data){

    $data['products']=$data['category']=[];


    if ($category=Categorie::where('url','=', $category_url)->first()){

        $category= $category->toArray();
        $data['category']=$category;
        $data['title']=$data['title']. ' | ' . $category['title'];


        if ($products=Categorie::find( $category['id'])->products){

            $data['products']= $products->toArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your controller:

```
if ( $category1 = Categorie::where('url', '=', $category_url)->first() ) {

    $products = Product::where('categorie_id', $category1->getAttribute('id'));
    $products = strtolower($sort) == 'asc' ? $products->orderBy('price'):$products->orderByDesc('price');
    $products = $products->get();

    return view('content.products', self::$data , compact('products', 'sort')); 
}
```

Comment: Changed that to this https://pastebin.com/57vFCA3r but still the order is not changing, the products stays on the same order

Comment: so the problem is in your query try [laravel debuger](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) to check the query

Comment: I chaecked the query and I got: "select * from `products` where `categorie_id` = ? order by `price` desc"  the proublem is in the categorie_id?